# Which lines to I change in order to avoid implicit declaration error

Tags: c, pointers

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

void alocare(int ***a, int n);
void citire(int **a, int n);
void afisare_matrice(int**a, int n);
void completare_random(int **a, int n);
void sortare_bubble_crescator(int *v, int n);
void sortare_selection_crescator(int *v, int n);
void sortare_insertion_crescator(int *v, int n);
void sortare_bubble_descrescator(int *v, int n);
void sortare_selection_descrescator(int *v, int n);
void sortare_insertion_descrescator(int *v, int n);
void eliberare_memorie(int **a, int n);
void sortare_vector(int *v, int n, bool crescator);
void inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(int **a, int n, int *v);
void meniu(int ***a, int *n);
int main() {
    int **A = NULL, n;
   meniu(&A, &n);
    int *vector = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (vector == NULL) {
        printf("Eroare la alocarea vectorului!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(A, n, vector);
    sortare_vector(vector, n, false); // Sortare descrescatoare
    printf("Vectorul sortat descrescator este: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", vector[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    eliberare_memorie(A, n);
    free(vector);
    return 0;
}

void meniu(int ***a, int *n) {
    printf("Introduceti dimensiunea matricei patratice: ");
    scanf("%d", n);
    alocare(a, *n);
    int option;
    do {
        printf("\n----------Meniu----------\n");
        printf("1. Crearea matricii de la tastatura\n");
        printf("2. Afisarea matricii\n");
        printf("3. Completare matrice cu valori aleatorii\n");
        printf("4. Sortare si afisare (Bubble Sort crescator)\n");
        printf("5. Sortare si afisare (Selection Sort crescator)\n");
        printf("6. Sortare si afisare (Insertion Sort crescator)\n");
        printf("7. Sortare si afisare (Bubble Sort descrescator)\n");
        printf("8. Sortare si afisare (Selection Sort descrescator)\n");
        printf("9. Sortare si afisare (Insertion Sort descrescator)\n");
        printf("0. Iesire\n");
        printf("Selectati o optiune: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                citire(*a, *n);
                break;
            case 2:
                afisare_matrice(*a, *n);
                break;    
            case 3:
                completare_random(*a, *n);
                break;
            case 4: {
                int *vector = malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
                if (vector == NULL) {
                    printf("Eroare la alocarea vectorului!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(*a, *n, vector);
                sortare_bubble(vector, *n, true);

                printf("Vectorul sortat cu Bubble Sort este: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
                    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                free(vector);
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                int *vector = malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
                if (vector == NULL) {
                    printf("Eroare la alocarea vectorului!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(*a, *n, vector);
                sortare_selection(vector, *n, true);

                printf("Vectorul sortat cu Selection Sort este: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
                    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                free(vector);
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                int *vector = malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
                if (vector == NULL) {
                    printf("Eroare la alocarea vectorului!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(*a, *n, vector);
                sortare_insertion(vector, *n, true);

                printf("Vectorul sortat cu Insertion Sort este: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
                    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                free(vector);
                break;
            case 7: {
                int *vector = malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
                if (vector == NULL) {
                    printf("Eroare la alocarea vectorului!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(*a, *n, vector);
                sortare_vector(vector, *n, false); // Sortare descrescatoare

                printf("Vectorul sortat cu Bubble Sort descrescator este: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
                    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                free(vector);
                break;
            }
            case 8: {
                int *vector = malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
                if (vector == NULL) {
                    printf("Eroare la alocarea vectorului!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(*a, *n, vector);
                sortare_vector(vector, *n, false); // Sortare descrescatoare

                printf("Vectorul sortat cu Selection Sort descrescator este: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
                    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                free(vector);
                break;
            }
            case 9: {
                int *vector = malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
                if (vector == NULL) {
                    printf("Eroare la alocarea vectorului!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(*a, *n, vector);
                sortare_vector(vector, *n, false); // Sortare descrescatoare

                printf("Vectorul sortat cu Insertion Sort descrescator este: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
                    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");

                free(vector);
                break;
                
            }
            case 0:
                printf("Iesire din program...\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Optiune invalida! Va rugam sa alegeti din nou.\n");
        }
    } while (option != 0);
}

void alocare(int ***a, int n) {
    *a = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    if (*a == NULL) {
        printf("Eroare la alocarea matricei!\n");
        exit(1);}
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (*a)[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        if ((*a)[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Eroare la alocarea matricei!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void citire(int **a, int n) {
    printf("Introduceti elementele matricei:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void afisare_matrice(int**a, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%i\t", a[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

void completare_random(int **a, int n) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
}

void sortare_bubble_crescator(int *v, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (v[j] > v[j + 1]) {
                int temp = v[j];
                v[j] = v[j + 1];
                v[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void sortare_selection_crescator(int *v, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int min_index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (v[j] < v[min_index]) {
                min_index = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[min_index];
        v[min_index] = temp;
    }
}

void sortare_insertion_crescator(int *v, int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int key = v[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && v[j] > key) {
            v[j + 1] = v[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        v[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

void sortare_bubble_descrescator(int *v, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (v[j] < v[j + 1]) {
                int temp = v[j];
                v[j] = v[j + 1];
                v[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void sortare_selection_descrescator(int *v, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int max_index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (v[j] > v[max_index]) {
                max_index = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[max_index];
        v[max_index] = temp;
    }
}

void sortare_insertion_descrescator(int *v, int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int key = v[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && v[j] < key) {
            v[j + 1] = v[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        v[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

void sortare_vector(int *v, int n, bool crescator) {
    if (crescator) {
        sortare_bubble_crescator(v, n);
    } else {
        sortare_bubble_descrescator(v, n);
    }
}
void inverseaza_elemente_col_div_trei(int **a, int n, int *v) {
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if ((j + 1) % 3 == 0) {
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                v[n - 1 - i] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void eliberare_memorie(int **a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
}
```

errors are:

```
gcc /tmp/j7dLWqPHfH.c -lm
/tmp/j7dLWqPHfH.c: In function 'meniu':
/tmp/j7dLWqPHfH.c:76:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sortare_bubble' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   76 |                 sortare_bubble(vector, *n, true);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/j7dLWqPHfH.c:94:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sortare_selection'; did you mean 'sortare_vector'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   94 |                 sortare_selection(vector, *n, true);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 sortare_vector
/tmp/j7dLWqPHfH.c:112:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sortare_insertion'; did you mean 'sortare_vector'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  112 |                 sortare_insertion(vector, *n, true);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 sortare_vector
/tmp/j7dLWqPHfH.c:186:1: error: expected 'while' before 'void'
  186 | void alocare(int ***a, int n) {
      | ^~~~
/tmp/j7dLWqPHfH.c:325:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
  325 | }
      | ^
```

Comment: Did you try adding declarations for the functions that the compiler said was missing?

Comment: The functions don't even have a definitions so just reorganizing the forward declarations isn't going to be enough.

Comment: You declared the functions in question with two arguments. But you try to use them with three arguments.

Comment: @Elec1 where do you see declarations?

Comment: @TedLyngmo where forward declarations are?

Comment: @gulpr There are neither forward declarations nor definitions for the functions the compiler complains about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the functions before calling them.
You probably think that you did, because of the prototypes at the start of the file.
But those declare functions with two parameters each and what you are calling are functions with three parameters.
Also while you do declare `sortare_bubble_crescator()` and `sortare_bubble_descrescator()` (with two parameters each) you do not declare what you call and what is mentioned in the error message: `sortare_bubble()`, with three parameters.
Similar for `sortare_bubble()` and  `sortare_selection_crescator()` and `sortare_selection_descrescator()`.
You need to make the prototype, the implementation/definition and the call agree on the parameters.
I guess that you had some kind of mapping in mind, where the function to call is selected from several specialised implementations, probably bases on the additional parameter.
But I cannot provide a way to do that, you probably need to return to design phase and go all the way with your interface design.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /tmp/j7dLWqPHfH.c:325:1: error: expected declaration or statement at
>       end of input   325 | }
>                          | ^
> ```

Your main problem is a missing **`}`** in the `meniu` function. Yor program will not compile at all. You need to correct it first.

Then you do not have definitions and prototypes of functions:

- `sortare_bubble`
- `sortare_selection`
- `sortare_insertion`

You need to write them.

most likely it chooses the correct function depending on the last boolean parameter. You can also use macrodefinitions

```
#define sortare_insertion(v,n,b) do{ \
                                    if(b) sortare_insertion_crescator(v,n); \
                                    else sortare_insertion_descrescator(v,n);\
                                    }while(0)
#define sortare_bubble(v,n,b) do{\
                                 if(b) sortare_bubble_crescator(v,n); \
                                 else sortare_bubble_descrescator(v,n);\
                                }while(0)
#define sortare_selection(v,n,b) do{\
                                    if(b) sortare_selection_crescator(v,n); \
                                    else sortare_selection_descrescator(v,n);\
                                   }while(0)
```

Also, you do not perform any error checks.